# Identifying a pattern in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DF:

| Game | Bookmaker | Over1.5 | Under1.5 | Over2.25 | Under2.25 | Over2.5 | Under2.5 | Over3 | Under3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A vs B | Asianodds | 1,2 | 3,4 | 2,1 | 4,1 | 3,1 | 4,7 | 3,3 | 4,9 |
| A vs B | Pinnacle | 1,2 | 3,4 | 2,1 | 4,0 | 3,1 | 4,6 | 3,3 | 4,9 |

How do I need to set up my python code to recognize a pattern as follows:

Find game where Pinnacle < Asianodds for Under2.25 & Under2.5 while Under in all other columns is equal for bookmaker & Over in all columns is equal for bookmaker

So far I tried this, but it does not give the desired outcome...:

```py
o_u_types= [1.50,1.75,2.00,2.25,2.50,2.75,3.00,3.50]
for i o_u_types:

                            data_df["Over_{}".format(i)]=Over #In these two lines Over and Under are the two previously scraped values for over and under
                            data_df["Under{}".format(i)]=Under

                            #Identify patterns
                            try:
                                Asian=data_df.iloc[0] #Asian is always line 1 of the df, Pin always line 2
                                Pin=data_df.iloc[1]
                                if Asian['Over_{}'.format(i)] > Pin['Over_{}'.format(i)]:
                                    data_df['over_dominance_{}'.format(i)]=='AsianDominant'
                                
                                elif Asian['Over_{}'.format(i)] < Pin['Over_{}'.format(i)]:
                                    data_df['over_dominance_{}'.format(i)]=='PinDominant'

                                elif Asian['Over_{}'.format(i)] == Pin['Over_{}'.format(i)]:
                                    data_df['over_dominance_{}'.format(i)]=='Parity'


                                if Asian['Under_{}'.format(i)] > Pin['Under_{}'.format(i)]:
                                    data_df['under_dominance_{}'.format(i)]=='AsianDominant'
                                
                                elif Asian['Under_{}'.format(i)] < Pin['Under_{}'.format(i)]:
                                    data_df['under_dominance_{}'.format(i)]=='PinDominant'

                                elif Asian['Under_{}'.format(i)] == Pin['Under_{}'.format(i)]:
                                    data_df['under_dominance_{}'.format(i)]=='Parity'

                                # data_df['over_diff']= Asian['Over'] != Pin['Over']
                                # data_df['under_diff']= Asian['Under'] != Pin['Under']

                                # print(data_df)
                            
                            except:
                                data_df['over_dominance_{}'.format(i)]= "n/a"
                                data_df['under_dominance_{}'.format(i)]= "n/a"
```

Sadly, this code returns n/a for all lines, even if there is a difference in the Over/Under values..

After I have established the dominance of one line over another, I want to identify a pattern where
Pinnacle < Asianodds for Under2.25 & Under2.5 while Under in all other columns is equal for bookmaker & Over in all columns is equal for bookmaker

Comment: can you share a few more rows as input, then share your expected output. I think there may be a simpler way to do this

Comment: In your code, you've got `Asian['Over'] > Pin['Over']` - but there are no columns "Over" or "Under". So what is that supposed to be? You've got `Over1.5`, `Over2.25`, `Over2.5`, `Over3` and you've got `Under1.5`, `Under2.25`, `Under2.5`, `Under3`. And what are the numbers `1,2`, `3,4`, `2,1` in the rows? Are they supposed to be tuples of numbers? Or floating point numbers with the comma as the decimal point indicator?

Comment: You are correct @aneroid - I have added my most recent code- hopefully it makes it clearer what I am trying to do?

Comment: why dont you do df.T and see what you get. You may be able to solve this better when the dataframe is transposed

Comment: Your question states `while Under in all other columns is equal`. That means you need an add to your if statement after the first if statement. Isnt it? Are you checking for Asian > Pin. The question statement and the code does not align.

Comment: Also in the data `1,2`, is `1` for `A` and `2` for `B` ?

Comment: @JoeFerndz no, it is one value with decimals for this match :) it is odds data for a soccer game

Comment: Can you please share what your expected result is. We may be able to address this using apply(lambda x:x....) option while iterating over the columns

Comment: @JoeFerndz in the first stage my expected result would be to understand the "dominance" of one row over the other within the Over{i}/Under{i} columns. Then in the second stage I want to utilize this dominance to identify matches based on rules (as for example the one mentioned above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is mostly right, just a bit messy.
I tried to make it cleaner and more concise.
So, assuming your original DataFrame with two rows is called `df`, here is my code:

```py
for i in o_u_types:
    asian_over = df.at[0, f"Over{i}"]
    asian_under = df.at[0, f"Under{i}"]
    pin_over = df.at[1, f"Over{i}"]
    pin_under = df.at[1, f"Under{i}"]

    if asian_over > pin_over:
        df[f"overdominant{i}"] = "AsianDominant"
    elif asian_over < pin_over:
        df[f"overdominant{i}"] = "PinDominant"
    else:
        df[f"overdominant{i}"] = "Parity"
...REST OF CODE LOGIC
```

I strongly recommend to use f-strings: so, for instance, `f"Over{i}"` instead of `"Over{}".format(i)`.
It is also recommended to finish each set of `if`-`elif` statements with an `else`. In your case, since `if` and `elif` test for `>` and `<` respectively, the `else` is necessarily `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if this is helpful to you.

You can Transpose your dataframe and do this as follows:

```
df = df.T
df.loc[df[0] > df[1],'over_dominance'] = 'AsianDominant'
df.loc[df[0] < df[1],'over_dominance'] = 'PinDominant'
df.loc[df[0] == df[1],'over_dominance'] = 'Parity'
print (df)
```

You can ignore the first 2 rows (Game and Bookmaker).

The output will be as follows:

```
                   0         1 over_dominance
Game          A vs B    A vs B         Parity
Bookmaker  Asianodds  Pinnacle    PinDominant
Over1.5          1,2       1,2         Parity
Under1.5         3,4       3,4         Parity
Over2.25         2,1       2,1         Parity
Under2.25        4,1       4,0  AsianDominant
Over2.5          3,1       3,1         Parity
Under2.5         4,7       4,6  AsianDominant
Over3            3,3       3,3         Parity
Under3           4,9       4,9         Parity
```

This may not be the final answer but I am trying to give you options to consider.